# Identify first event or last non-event

Tags: stata

I have the following data in Stata:

```
clear

* Input data
input float id str7 event time
id  event   time
1   "." 10
1   "." 20
1   "1" 30
1   "0" 40
1   "." 50
2   "0" 10
2   "0" 20
2   "0" 30
2   "0" 40
2   "0" 50
3   "1" 10
3   "1" 20
3   "0" 30
3   "." 40
3   "." 50
4   "." 10
4   "." 20
4   "." 30
4   "." 40
4   "." 50
5   "1" 10
5   "1" 20
5   "1" 30
5   "1" 40
5   "1" 50     
end
```

Below is data I hope to get to:

```
* Input data
input float id str7 event time
id1 event1  time1
1   1   30
2   0   50
3   1   10
4   .   50
5   1   10

end
```

My aim is to take the first row for each `id` of an event equal to `1`. If an `id` has no event for any time, then I want to report the last time of the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
replace event = "-1" if event == "1"

bysort id (event time): generate tag1 = event[_n==1] == "-1" 
bysort id (event time): generate tag2 = event[_n==_N] == "0" 
bysort id (event time): generate tag3 = event[_n==_N] == "."

replace event = "1" if event == "-1"
keep if tag1 == 1 | tag2 == 1 | tag3 == 1

list

     +----------------------------------------+
     | id   event   time   tag1   tag2   tag3 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |  1       1     30      1      0      0 |
  2. |  2       0     50      0      1      0 |
  3. |  3       1     10      1      0      0 |
  4. |  4       .     50      0      0      1 |
  5. |  5       1     10      1      0      0 |
     +----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it:

```
bysort id (time): egen when_first_1 = min(cond(event == "1", time, .))
by id: gen tokeep = cond(when_first_1 == ., time == time[_N], time == when_first_1) 
keep if tokeep 
drop tokeep
```

See especially Section 9 in [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055).

Answer (score 1):

This is based on an answer by Romalpa Akzo [on Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1469251-select-first-event-or-last-non-event):

```
bys id (time): gen tag = 1 if  event == "1" | _n ==_N
bys id (tag time): keep if _n == 1
drop tag
```

I think that's the neatest answer to date. Note how it hinges on `tag` being missing if it is not `1`.