# Keep first record when event occurrs

Tags: stata, data-cleaning, recode, longitudinal

I have the following data in Stata:

```
clear

* Input data
input grade id exit time
1   1   .   10
2   1   .   20
3   1   2   30
4   1   0   40
5   1   .   50
1   2   0   10
2   2   0   20
3   2   0   30
4   2   0   40
5   2   0   50
1   3   1   10
2   3   1   20
3   3   0   30
4   3   .   40
5   3   .   50
1   4   .   10
2   4   .   20
3   4   .   30
4   4   .   40
5   4   .   50
1   5   1   10
2   5   2   20
3   5   1   30
4   5   1   40
5   5   1   50

end
```

The objective is to take the first row foreach id when a event occurs and if no event occur then take the last report foreach id. Here is a example for the data I hope to attain

```
* Input data
input grade id  exit    time
3   1   2   30
5   2   0   50
1   3   1   10
5   4   .   50
1   5   1   10
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of an event appears to be that `exit` is not zero or missing. If so, then all you need to do is tweak the code in my previous answer:

```
bysort id (time): egen when_first_e = min(cond(exit > 0 & exit < ., time, .))
by id: gen tokeep = cond(when_first_e == ., time == time[_N], time == when_first_e)
```

Previous thread was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182249/identify-first-event-or-last-non-event).

Comment: ID 5 has EVENT 1 at TIME 10 but then also EVENT 2 at TIME 20. How is it possible to keep this information separately? For example if 1 is a CITATION and 2 is EXPELLED. This example shows ID 5 got citation but that they get EXPELLED is ignored. If it is actually important to generate indicator variable for order of events how may I incorporate such information? @Nick Cox

Comment: That sounds a sufficiently different question that you should favour us with (1) a new thread (2) example data (3) your attempt at code.

Comment: What about in this example above here if instead of taking the last any response but instead want to take the last response equals to 0?